# Creating a function using cURL - returning cURL data then reusing?

Tags: php, curl

I want to create a function using cURL and the bit.ly API to shorten links.

My question is, how can I get the string of data returned by cURL and continue to use it throughout the function (as this doesn't seem to work, I'd assume due to the attempt to `return $string` and then use string in the rest of the function).

**Here's what I have, which just displays a blank page:**

```
function shorten_url($bit_login,$bit_api,$long_url) {
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?login=".$bit_login."&apiKey=".$bit_api."&longUrl=".$long_url."&format=xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $string;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$short_url = $xml->data[0]->url;
echo $short_url;
}

shorten_url($login,$apikey,"http://www.google.com");
```

I've also tried to `return $short_url` and echo it ouside of the function, after the function is run (below `shorten_url()`), which doesn't work either.

Comment: Where $string comes from on the "return"? try: $string = curl_exec($ch);

Comment: I thought the first return after cURL would be the fetched data, such as in - http://snipplr.com/view/4084/. I'll try your suggestion now :).

Comment: Worked perfectly :), do you want to run that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function will return NULL. You are missing the `$string = curl_exec($ch);`